# Count the number of occurances of an attribute

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS, how can I count the number of occurrences of a specific attribute (`data-page` in this case)?

I have several pseudo pages that are shown to the user upon swipe, and I wish to prevent the page counter from exceeding the number of pages.  I've set my containers up as follows, but if anyone has any better ideas for how I can do this, I'd be open to suggestions -

**My HTML (sample)** -

```
<body class="single single-post postid-5 single-format-standard ng-scope" data-ng-swipe-right="prevPage()" data-ng-swipe-left="nextPage()" data-ng-controller="bodyCtrl">
    <div id="main">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="allowed page page-1 visible" data-page="1">

                <div class="mask"></div>
                <div class="inner">
                    { page content }
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**My controller** -

```
myApp.controller('bodyCtrl', function($scope){

    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.getMaxPage = function(){
        { Not sure how??? }
    }
    $scope.maxPage = $scope.getMaxPage();

    $scope.nextPage = function(){
        $scope.currentPage = ($scope.currentPage >= $scope.maxPage) ? $scope.maxPage : $scope.currentPage + 1;
    }

    $scope.prevPage = function(){
        $scope.currentPage = ($scope.currentPage > 1) ? $scope.currentPage - 1 : 1;
    }

    $scope.isVisible = function(page){
        return ($scope.currentPage >= page);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can select the count using jquery, If you are using jquery along with angular or you prefer to do it as below go for it.

```
//count the number of occurrences of the `data-page` attribute.
var count = $('[data-page]').length;
```

here is a [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/f6nwmIpPK1S6VjltvbaV?p=preview)

If you prefer to not to use `jquery` then do it in plain old javascript way.

```
//select all element with the data-page attribute
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-page]');
var count = elements.length; // get the number of occurrences.
```

here is a [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/z9zwcsCnj6kS4IM4UEwC?p=preview)